# Array Diff with some options

Tags: php, array-difference

I have some text blocks (they are values of array), which should be compared with another file using [array_diff()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php).
For example, in the following text blocks:

**Base of Comparison:**

```
interface Vlan22
description VPN Inside
ip address 10.1.1.1 255.255.255.0
ip tcp adjust-mss 1260
!
```

**First Sample:**

```
interface Vlan22
description VPN Inside
ip address 10.2.2.2 255.255.255.0      <===========
ip tcp adjust-mss 1260
!
```

**Second Sample:**

```
interface Vlan22
description VPN Inside
ip address 10.1.1.1 255.255.255.0
ip tcp adjust-mss 1260
shutdown                               <===========
!
```

How to know that in the "First Sample" the difference with the base file is in "ip address" line, and in the second one it's in an additional "shutdown" line?

Comment: What kind of result would you expect? "Knowing" isn't something PHP can do, you can only come up with some specific data structure or value…

Comment: I want to know the line of difference. line which starts with "ip address" in the first sample and the line contains "shutdown" for the second one.

Comment: Should I use some regex to compare? @deceze